# how do I echo a website-linked photo in php?

Tags: php, html, image, hyperlink

I've looked at every other example of the problem I'm having and none have covered how to do an actual website URL link within an echoed image in PHP. I'm sure I have to use an escape character of some sort but I'm not sure where or which one. here is my code

```
<?php
echo "<a href=\'https://validator.w3.org/nu/"><img src="HTMLVALIDATIONIMAGE.png"  /></a>";
echo "<a href=\'https://validator.w3.org/nu/"><img src="CSSVALIDATIONIMAGE.png"  /></a>"";
echo "<b>Last Modified:</b> " . date('F d Y h:i A', filemtime($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
?>
```

Comment: The starting and ending quotes of an HTML attribute have to match. If you start with `'`, you can't end with `"`.

Comment: You don't need to escape single quotes inside a double-quoted string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes around the HTML attributes when you're using double quotes around the PHP string. Then you don't need to escape anything.

```
echo "<a href='https://validator.w3.org/nu/'><img src='HTMLVALIDATIONIMAGE.png'></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You, of course can [omit](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/syntax.html#unquoted) the quotes in HTML5 :

```php
<?php
echo "<a href=https://validator.w3.org/nu/><img src=HTMLVALIDATIONIMAGE.png></a>";
echo "<a href=https://validator.w3.org/nu/><img src=CSSVALIDATIONIMAGE.png ></a>";
echo "<b>Last Modified:</b> " . date('F d Y h:i A', filemtime($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

Making your code more readable.

```
<?php
echo "<a href='https://validator.w3.org/nu/'><img src='HTMLVALIDATIONIMAGE.png'  /></a>";
echo "<a href='https://validator.w3.org/nu/'><img src='CSSVALIDATIONIMAGE.png'  /></a>";
echo "<b>Last Modified:</b> " . date('F d Y h:i A', filemtime($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
?>
```